# Right XML form for a given XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am writing a test tomorrow and have to learn a bit of XML. I've got a XML-Schema and have to write a fitting XML-File.

The given schema:

```
<schema> 
<element name="meta" type="metaType"/> 
<complexType name="metaType"> 
  <sequence> 
    <element name="title" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> 
    <element name="authors" type="authorsType"/> 
    <element name="description" type="languageEntryType"/> 
    <element name="keywords" type="languageEntryType"/> 
  </sequence> 
</complexType> 
<complexType name="authorsType"> 
  <sequence> 
    <element name="name" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
  </sequence> 
</complexType> 
<complexType name="languageEntryType"> 
  <sequence> 
    <element name="entry" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
      <complexType> 
        <attribute name="language"/> 
      </complexType> 
    </element> 
  </sequence> 
</complexType> 
</schema>
```

My solution looks like:

```
<meta>
  <title>Sonne</title>
  <authors>Rammstein</authors>
  <description>Second Track on the Album "Mutter"</description>
  <keywords>hard rock</keywords>
  <keywords>metal</keywords>
</meta>
```

Is this about right? What is the attribut for, do I have to mind it?
Thanks for any help!

//edit: I did a bit more of research and now my guess would be:

```
<meta>
  <title>Sonne</title>
  <authors>Rammstein</authors>
  <description>Second Track on the Album "Mutter"</description>
  <keywords language="english">hard rock</keywords>
  <keywords language="english">metal</keywords>
</meta>
```

Comment: Wait, are you *writing* the test for others to do, or are you *doing* the test yourself?

Comment: Also, have you tried validating your file in an XML editor with that schema? That would answer your question instantly.

Comment: Hey Mr Stormtrooper, I am writing a test and learning for it right now, XML was only a topic we discussed very briefly. I've never used or seen an XML-Editor and do not know how to link a XML-File with a scheme. I could teach it myself but that would cost 2 hours or so, a quick answer would help me to be sure I did understand it correctly and could go to bed :P
Bye

Comment: You are administering a test in something you don't understand? Perhaps I can recommend *don't do that!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to check if an XML document conforms with a given schema is to validate it against that schema with an XML editor or tool. [This is a free online tool you can use for just such an exercise](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html).

Having a quick check of your schema, the first problem is the xml-schema isn't valid, so no document can validate against it. I've added namespaces, but this is still incomplete and you'll need to correct that before you can determine if a document is valid against it.

I was able to help fix it to here, but the schema is still riddled with errors. No document can conform to this schema without a lot of corrections.

```
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>  
    <xs:element name="meta" type="metaType"/> 
    <xs:complexType name="metaType"> 
      <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> 
        <xs:element name="authors" type="authorsType"/> 
        <xs:element name="description" type="languageEntryType"/> 
        <xs:element name="keywords" type="languageEntryType"/> 
      </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType> 
    <xs:complexType name="authorsType"> 
      <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
      </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType> 
    <xs:complexType name="languageEntryType"> 
      <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="language" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element> 
      </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType> 
  </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks alot I will search for the incomplete parts.

Comment: Yeah I am getting a lot of errors, I gues the given task was pseudocode XML.

The test will not be hard to fail because the main topics are different. And if it's possible to get a few more points from a task like this which doesn't look too hard I will try to learn it.